# Keras / NN - Handling NaN, missing input

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

These days I'm trying to teach myself machine learning and I'm going though some issues with my dataset.

Some of my rows (I work with csv files that I create with some js script, I feel more confident doing that in js) are empty which is normal as I'm trying to build some guessing model but the issue is that it results in having `nan` values on my training set.

My NN was not training so I added a piece of code to remove them from my set, but now I have some issues where my model can't work with input from different size.

So my question is: how do I handle missing data? (I basically have 2 rows and can only have the value from 1 and can't merge them as it will not give good results)

I can remove it from my set, which would reduce the accuracy of my model in the end.

PS: if needed I'll post some code when I come back home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the same input size during training and inference. If you have a **few missing values (a few %)**, you can always choose to **replace the missing values by a 0** or by the **average of the column**. If you have more missing values **(more than 50%)** you are probably better off **ignoring the column completely**. Note that this theoretical, the best way to make it work is to try different strategies on your data.

Comment: Merci @Benjamin Breton. For now i'm just gonna ignore it but still have that data on the side and maybe try to implement it when i get my model to work and give good enough result.